# React App Not Loading into The Packaged Electron App

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to package my react app with electron 8. I've followed the instructions in this article and made the necessary changes to suit my code:

https://medium.com/@johndyer24/building-a-production-electron-create-react-app-application-with-shared-code-using-electron-builder-c1f70f0e2649

**Here's what I'm currently seeing after packaging.**
[image: Electron Package]

**Here's my package.json**

```
 {
  "homepage": "./",
  "name": "Asset_Viewer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.5",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "wait-on": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.42.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "build-electron": "mkdir build\\src > nul & robocopy src\\shared build\\src\\shared /s > nul & robocopy electron build\\electron /s > nul || exit 0",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-pack": "electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",
    "preelectron-pack": "npm run build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.icom.icomuav",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "electron": "^8.2.5",
    "electron-builder": "^22.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

Basically this are the order which I run the scripts to package the whole thing.

1. build
2. build-electron
3. electron-pack

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Same with vuejs app packaged by vue-cli plugins electron-builder. It seems that dealing with electron and perhaps webpack compiler...

Answer (score 4):

I know that I'm late to this, but I spent days tracking this issue down.

I ran `npm run build` first to package my react application so that i would actually *have*  a build folder.

In my case, after using electron-forge to package my application, inside `index.html` all of my local imports to my .js files were missing the '.' before "/static/js/etc.js".

example: [image]

example 2: [image]

once changing it to the correct one as shown, it loaded everything just fine: [image]

I really hope this helps someone.

Comment: THIS EXPLAINS IT, THANK YOU GOOD SIR

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i found out that the problem was that in build/index.html external resources were not linked well:

```
<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.4acc3563.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.4acc3563.js"></script>
```

You can notice that there is a missing `'.'`.

The solution that I found was to add the following to `package.json`:

```
...

"homepage": "./",

...
```

After that I rebuilt the app making sure to re-run even react rebuild command and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to log the current route to the console, so you can see what page is loaded when you open both the development and the production build.

It might be caused by the router. In your project you probably have only 1 real HTML page - `index.html`, so make sure it loads `/index.html` and not `/index.html/#` (hash mode) or something.

Also try to add this event listener in your `main` process:

```js
// Replace YOUR_WINDOW and modify the line that loads the URL 
// (the same way you load URL when the window is created)
YOUR_WINDOW.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    YOUR_WINDOW.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
})
```